# what is the best way to update component color/font globally in `materia-ui`?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `material-ui` for my react project and I found `material-ui` uses `makeStyles` to create the style object. Then inject the styles object as `classes` into each component. It seems `styles` is bind with each component. My question is how I can define some globally used styles like `font`, `color` etc. In `css / scss`, I can define some global variables and I can change them in the css files which will apply to all other components. What is the best way to do that in `material-ui` styles?

```
...

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});


return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the customization of [Theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)